# How to Override Payment Helper Data Method Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, payment-methods, plugin, preference

I am trying to override Magento Payment Helper data in my extension but it's not working.

I have overriden by using the preference method.

I have put below code in `app/code/Demo/PaymentTest/etc/di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Payment\Helper\Data" type="Demo\PaymentTest\Helper\Data" />
```

Here is my Helper code

```
<?php
namespace Demo\PaymentTest\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
{
    public function getStoreMethods($store = null, $quote = null)
    {
    }
}
```

I am trying to override `getStoreMethods` method in my helper but it's not calling it.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Depending on the reason why you want to rewrite that method using plugins would be more appropriate

Comment: Please share code how can i rewrite that method by using plugins? I want to restrict payment method.

Comment: @SanjayJethva, what Magento version do you use? Since Magento 2.1.3 `\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data::getStoreMethods` is deprecated and doesn't call anymore, use `\Magento\Payment\Model\PaymentMethodList::getActiveList` instead

Comment: Hello @jonijones, Its working and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite payment method, I suggest you use a plugin.

Create the following `di.xml` in the `etc` folder of your module:

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Helper\Data">
        <plugin name="restrictPaymentMethods" type="Demo\PaymentTest\Plugin\RestrictPaymentMethods" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create `Plugin\RestrictPaymentMethods.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Demo\PaymentTest\Plugin;

class RestrictPaymentMethods
{

    public function afterGetStoreMethods(\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $subject, $result)
    {
        // $result will contain the original result
        // You can modify the $result array to restrict the payment methods
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @raphael-at-digital-pianism, Thanks for your answer. I have tried your code but its not working. File is calling but method is not calling.
Thanks